# Does it hold that $P(A|C)\,P(B|A)=P(A,B|C)?$

Tags: conditional-probability

I hope this is the right forum to ask this question in.

I have the following equality that intuitively I feel is correct. However, I am having trouble proving it. Maybe my intuition is off?

Considering three events A,B and C, I am trying to figure out if it holds that

$$P(A|C)\,P(B|A)=P(A,B|C).$$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include this in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Counterexample: suppose we flip a fair coin. Let $C$ be the event "it lands on heads", let $B$ be the event "it lands on tails", and let $A$ be the event "it lands on heads or tails".

The correct statement would be:

$$
P(A, B | C) = P(A|C)P(B|A,C)
$$

So your version would be wrong whenever $P(B|A,C) \ne P(B|A)$ and $P(A|C) \ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out a different way of proving my statement, so luckily my argumentation did not end up relying on this.